# wordpress - how to create custom css box in my theme

Tags: wordpress

I am coding WordPress theme and need to create custom CSS box like Addition CSS of BasicStore theme. Please tell me how to do that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/377D5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many different ways
I prefer ACF options page (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/) but I thinks this available only with POR version.
Then you can use WP options page (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_options_page/)
or customizer (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register)